# Using Shared Dataset in Subreport

Tags: ssrs-2008

Greetings!

I am using SSRS with MS SQL Server 2008 R2, which has the new feature of supporting shared datasets.

First, I created my shared dataset, and made sure that it worked correctly and had a good connection. That worked great.

Second, I created a new report (Let's call it "ReportSub"), and I had it use my shared dataset. The report works great.

Third, I created another report (Let's call is "ReportMain"), and I put a subreport object into the report and associated it with "ReportSub". Doesn't work. Instead, I get this error:

Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'ReportSub', located at: /ReportSub. Please check the log files for more information.

Any ideas of what the problem may be? It will work if I use an embedded dataset, but I really need to use a shared dataset.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Currently, there is no way to Preview the subreport with shared datasource/dataset in BIDS.

Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/74e51434-1d14-4fb1-9b1c-1a394c187b2f

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem for "preview" only. As soon as I deploy this to Reporting Service server it  starts working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when previewing my MainReport. The SubReport preview works fine, but the MainReport preview produces the error "Data retrieval failed for the subreport".

**The solution is not use shared dataset in the SubReport but an embedded daaset!**

I have also observed that some changes in the SubReport are not taken over by the MainReport. So I had to close and repoen the project again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem even after deploying.  I discovered that I was prompting for datasource credentials in the subreport, but not in the main report.

After I made them both the same (prompt for credentials or set them both to use the provided credentials), the problem went away and I was able to preview.

Comment: Where do you specify the credentials? On the data source?