# Data retrieval failed for subreport (reporting services)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I researched my problem and these solutions did not work for me:

[Getting the error "Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1'" while trying to preview a report from Business Intelligence Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061147/getting-the-error-data-retrieval-failed-for-the-subreport-subreport1-while)
[Using Shared Dataset in Subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974587/using-shared-dataset-in-subreport)

My situation: running visual studio report designer (visual studio 2008, version 9) on my local laptop. I have a main report A which contains multiple subreports. To test the subreports individually, each subreport has a 'wrapper' main report B (or C etc.) which passes the same parameters as main report A would. So, running main report B to test the subreport (lets call it Details) gives the 'Data retrieval failed for the subreport'. Subreport Details uses a shared dataset. I switched it to an embedded query, checked all parameters. The query on which the shared dataset is based runs no problem in sql server management studio. Now the strange thing, as soon as I deploy the main and subreport to the report server, and I run them directly on the server, the error is gone and the report works!

This seems very strange to me and I am desperately trying to find out what I can do. I have had no success in finding logs on my machine that can help. Is there any way of getting logs from reporting services. Otherwise, any ideas on how this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the problem is probably the path you are specifying for the location of the subreport. Are you using a full URL or just a relative path like `Content/MyReport.rdl`. You may not be able to access the published version of the subreport locally, but of course you can once the main report is also published.

Comment: Both the main and subreport are stored locally using a full path c:\Users\......

Comment: It doesn't matter where you store them locally. The point is that you can point to the local version of the subreport during design, but you'll need to change the path in the properties to point to the deployed subreport when you deploy the main report.